# Girsanov theorem and filtrations

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, filtrations, radon-nikodym

Let $\{W_t\}$ be a standard Wiener process on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$. Let $\mathcal{F}^W$ be the natural filtration generated by $\{W_t\}$.

Let $\{\theta_t\}$ be an $\mathcal{F}_t^W$-adapted stochastic process satisfying 
$$
E_P\left[ \exp\left(\int_0^t  \frac{\theta_s^2}{2} ds\right) \right]<\infty , \forall t\geq 0,
$$ 
Then, the process
$$
\varepsilon_t = \exp\left(\int_0^t\theta_s dW_s - \frac{1}{2}\int_0^t\theta^2_s ds\right)
$$ 
is an $\mathcal{F}^W_t$-martingale (because Novikov's condition is satisfied) and it represents the Radon-Nikodym derivative $dQ/dP$ for some $Q$ that is equivalent to $P$. We also have that $\{X_t\}$ defined by $X_t=\int_0^t dW_s -\int_0^t\theta_sds $ is a standard Wiener process on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}^W, Q)$.

My question: Take the natural filtration generated by $\{X_t\}$, $\mathcal{F}^X$. What is the relationship between $\mathcal{F}^W$and $\mathcal{F}^X$? Do they coincide?

Comment: Since $X_t=W_t-\int_0^t \theta_sds$ and $\theta$ is $\mathcal F^W$-adapted, it is clear that $\mathcal F^X_t \subset \mathcal F^W_t$. The other direction... I suspect it is true but cannot seem to prove it.

Comment: Ah, the reverse can be proved true if (for instance) $\theta_s = b(s,W_{\cdot})$ for some Lipchitz function $b$ which is predictable with respect to the canonical filtration on $C([0,\infty))$. This follows from the fact that the SDE $dB_s = dX_s + \int_0^t b(s, B_{\cdot}) ds$ satisfies existence and pathwise uniqueness (hence strong solutions). I think you would need to complete the filtrations though.

Comment: @Shalop Is the $\subset, \supset$ regardless of the probability measure?

Comment: I think it's right the way it's written, regardless of probability space.